# How Do I Update My SQL(Postgresql) Database With New Information From An Array?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to store the interests of a user. I was wondering what is the best way or an example in which I could do so. The interest could already be in the table. How would I be able to take out any interests that are not in the new interest array and add the interests that are not in the table for a particular user?

Example:

Interest Array: ['Dance', 'Art', 'Singing','Surfing'];

User Id: 4

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE interests (
interests_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(user_id),
passion TEXT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO interests (user_id, passion)
VALUES (1, 'Volleyball'), 
     (1, 'Football'),
     (2, 'Football'),
     (2, 'EDM'),
     (2, 'Art'),
     (3, 'EDM'),
     (3, 'Surfing'),
     (4, 'Volleyball'),
     (4, 'Dance');
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Hi! I am using postgressql!